# PHP - Parse text file with fixed column width

Tags: php, database, laravel, parsing

I'm new to PHP and Laravel and I need to open the file and parse the contents to pass them to the database. The text file has fixed column width. It doesn't have delimiters or headers. I think using substrings and assigning each of them to a variable would be the correct approach, but I'm still in the process of learning the language and I have no idea how to implement this.

Here is an example of the data that is inside the text file:

```
1618 0002 9                    1261    4141191269    4141191269       4      002     0

1606 0000 9                    1159    4169191388    4169191388       4      012     0

1607 0009 7    9  505   04129284134          1245          1245 56984 4         

1619 0000 9    6               1172    2129922686    2129922686       4      013     0

1606 0000 9                    1159    4169191388    4169191388       4      012     0

1607 0009 7    9  505   04129284134          1245          1245 56984 4         

1619 0000 7    6  521         1188#          1172          1172       0          001 4

1606 0000 9                    1159    4169191388    4169191388       4      012     0

1607 0009 7    9  505   04129284134          1245          1245 56984 4         

1619 0000 9    6               1252    2129922686    2129922686       4      003     0

1606 0000 9                    1159    4169191388    4169191388       4      012     0

1607 0009 7    9  505   04129284134          1245          1245 56984 4         

1619 0000 7    6  521         1188#          1252          1252       1          002 4
```

### EDIT:

Column names:

```
id
time
duration
cond_code
code_dial
code_used
dialed_num
calling_num
clg_num_in_tac
auth_code
frl
ixc_code
in_crt_id
out_crt_id
```

Comment: is this a one time insert or part of the ongoing laravel project?  do you know the column names and can you share the associated database column names?

Comment: sounds like you have the basics, so write some code.

Comment: This is an ongoing laravel project. I edited the original post and added the column names.

Comment: this might help :http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp

Comment: once you got the data then split with new line '\n' for rows and '\t' for cells in order to get an array with your data

Comment: see the CSV parsing example [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Just set the delimiter to `"\t"`. it will be more performant and robust than randomly splitting on things like these guys suggest.

Comment: It wouldn't work with `"\t"` as a delimiter. Take the first string for example, there is "missing" data that is filled with blank spaces or tabs in the 4th column, but it is still data. So if I take tabs as delimiters it wont parse the file correctly. @mpen "The optional delimiter parameter sets the field delimiter (one character only)."  `"\t"` can't be used as a delimiter with `fgetcsv`

Comment: @malandriso Sure it can, I just tried it to make sure. `"\t"` *is* only one char. Is your data malformed? Missing columns are perfectly fine. `"a\t\tb\tc"` will parse as `["a","","b","c"]` for example. If you've got random numbers of spaces/tabs inbetween there...then I don't know how anyone is supposed to parse that.

Comment: @malandriso If those really are just spaces, and there are no tabs...and everything is *perfectly* aligned, then you can do a bunch of `substr` magic to pull out each column. `substr($line,0,4)` for example will be the `id` column, and then `substr($line, 5, 4)` will be time...and so forth.

Comment: I tried the example you linked me to using `"\t"` as a delimiter and I get this in return:

`1 fields in line 1: 

1618 0002 9 1261 4141191269 4141191269 4 002 0
1 fields in line 2: 


1 fields in line 3: 

1606 0000 9 1159 4169191388 4169191388 4 012 0
1 fields in line 4: 


1 fields in line 5: 

1607 0009 7 9 505 04129284134 1245 1245 56984 4`

Comment: @mpen I managed to get it to work with substrings but I still need to delete all the blank lines before processing the data. Any suggestions?

Comment: @malandriso Pre-process it. If you do a regex find-and-replace on `^\n` it should pick out the blank lines which you can replace with nothing. If the dataset is small enough, use your favourite code editor (sublime, atom, phpstorm,...). Or you can probably use `sed` on linux. I'm not a sed expert, but I think it's something like `sed s/^\n// filename.csv`.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why everyone is suggesting ways to parse tab delimited files. Use [unpack()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php). I used to do this by manually parsing files and writing functions to extract the data-—what a waste of time. I found this [article](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/php-cookbook/1565926811/ch01s11.html) that explained how to do it in a clean self-documenting way.

`$records[] = unpack('A40Address 1/A40Address 2/A25City/A2State/A10Zip Code',$row);`

Answer (score 0):

Use file and Laravel collections:

```
Route::get('/import', function()
{
    $lines = collect(file(__DIR__.'/file.txt'))->map(function($item) {
        return explode("\t", $item);
    });

    dd($lines);
});
```

Given this, tab delimited, file:

```
1618    0002    9   1261    4141191269  4141191269  4   002 0
1606    0000    9   1159    4169191388  4169191388  4   012 0
1606    0000    9   1159    4169191388  4169191388  4   012 0
```

And you should get something like

[image]